# How do i make my input take all int and str type of data

Tags: python-3.x, input

I'm trying to get a guessing game with the user input as an answer and if the user type exit the game will show the amount of time the player tried but the program won't run because it can only take either interger or string type.

```js
import random
while True:
    number = random.randint(1,9)
    guess = int(input('guess the number: '))
    time = 0
    time += 1
    if guess == number:
        print('you guessed correct')
    elif guess < number:
        print('your guessed is lower than the actual number')
    elif guess > number:
        print('your guessed is higher than the actual number')
    elif guess == 'exit':
        print(time)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
import random

time = 0
number = random.randint(1,9)

while True:
    guess = input('guess the number: ')
    time += 1
    if guess == "exit":
        print(time)
        break
    elif int(guess) < number:
        print('your guessed is lower than the actual number')
    elif int(guess) > number:
        print('your guessed is higher than the actual number')
    elif int(guess) == number:
        print('you guessed correct')
        print(time)
        break
```

note that time and number have to be initializate outside the while loop, because if not, we would get different random numbers for each iteration, and also time would be initializate to 0 each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the input as a string first before converting it to an integer:

```
while True:
    response = input('guess the number: ')
    if response == 'exit':
        break
    guess = int(response)
    # the rest of your code testing guess as a number
```